# MongoDB: How to remove a property from all objects in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I want to unset a property from all items in an array of objects in MongoDB.

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eUCtaUKOecU)

---

**Explanation:**

Suppose I have an array of objects with the following structure in a document:

```
{
    "key": 1,
    "questions": [
      {
        "text": "Q1",
        "explanation": "Howdy?"
      },
      {
        "text": "Q2",
        "explanation": "Pizza"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove the property `explanation` from all the objects in the `questions` array.

How can I achieve that?

I was hoping something like the following would work:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "questions.explanation": 1
  }
})
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#:%7E:text=Definition,-%24%5B%5D&text=The%20all%20positional%20operator%20%24%5B%5D,in%20the%20specified%20array%20field.&text=For%20an%20example%2C%20see%20Update%20All%20Elements%20in%20an%20Array.) all positional operator to remove the field from all elements in the array.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "questions.$[].explanation": 1
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5v8zk6_pZap)